# Определить количество членов ряда, сравнить полученное значение суммы ряда со значением функции

Tags: python, математика

Необходимо определить количество членов ряда, сравнить полученное значение суммы ряда со значением функции.
Выдает в принте nan, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Определить количество членов ряда, сравнить полученное значение суммы ряда со
значением функции (левая часть представленного выражения)
с точностью e = 0.001

S в приние выводит nan , почему так ?

```
from math import atan
x = float(input('x = '))
e0 = ((1+x*x)*atan(x)-x)/2
x2kf = 1
s = 0
el = x
eps = 1e-3
k = 1
while abs(s-e0)>eps:
    s += el
    x2kf *= -x*x
    el *= 1/(4*k*k-1)*x2kf
    k += 1
print(s, ((1+x*x)*atan(x)-x)/2)
```

Comment: выглядит так, что ряд расходящийся  x в i-й степени растет быстрее, чем i в квадрате, и просто переполнение возникает по ходу дела

Comment: и как это исправить ?

Comment: Что-то и формула какая-то кривая, и про `x` ничего не сказано - в каком оно диапазоне может быть, или любое вообще?

Answer (score 2):

В вашем вопросе есть сразу несколько проблем.

Во-первых, вы не указали, для какого `x` у вас выводится `nan`, поэтому у нас нет возможности воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Во-вторых, у вас в учебнике приведена неверная формула "*функционального ряда*". Суммирование должно начинаться с 1, а не с 0.

В-третьих, у вас неверно вычисляется `el`. Вы вычисляете `el *= 1/(4*k*k-1)*x2kf`, то есть у вас показатель степени растёт не линейно по `k`, а квадратично. Использовать `*=` для вычисления `el` - неверно.

В-четвёртых, у ряда Тейлора для арктангенса радиус сходимости равен 1, поэтому `x` должен быть от -1 до +1.

Итого:
ограничьте `x` и исправьте вычисление ряда:

```
eps = 1e-6
x2kf = x
sign = -1
s = 0
k = 0
while abs(s-e0)>eps:
    k += 1
    x2kf *= x*x
    sign *= -1
    el = sign*x2kf/(4*k*k-1)
    s += el
```

PS. Я не понял, почему ряд назван "функциональным". Обычно такие полиномиальные ряды называются рядами Тейлора. Функциональными называют бесконечные суммы всяких синусов-косинусов и других функций.